# Redis SCARD result does not match size of the set returned by SMEMBERS

Tags: redis

According to Redis documentation, [SMEMBERS](https://redis.io/commands/smembers) returns the whole set by some key. While another command - [SCARD](https://redis.io/commands/scard) - returns cardinality (size) of the set.

In my case SMEMBERS returns set of 22899 elements for some key, while SCARD returns just '2' for the same key. How can I explain this fact?

Redis version is 2.8.24

I'm running redis commands with redis-cli:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> scard myfancykey
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> myfancykey
....(22898 results go here)
22899) "my-fancy-value-63899173647738-foo[bar-baz:12343123]"
```

Comment: Please provide example code of what you have that results in this behavior.

Comment: Just updated the question. I'm calling redis from redis-cli

Comment: There's no explanation that I'm aware of - try upgrading to a more current version of Redis.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? If so that's one hell of a bug!

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer need to work that example out. Unfortunately, I got this case occasionally from production database

Answer (score -2):

Looks like I shot myself in the foot. Redis works normally, at the end.